# Is there a way to render a html page without view model?

Tags: django

Is there a way to render a html page without having a view model in django if a page is going to display only static html?

Also, can I redirect to a html page instead of a url? For example, instead of doing this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('form/success/')
```

can I do this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('success.html')
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For static HTML you could use [Flatpages app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/).

You could also serve rendered templates (which could contain only static HTML) but you will need a view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def some_view(request):
   return render_to_response('sometemplate.html')
```

About redirection, basically you can't redirect to HTML page by just giving the filename, even if it were statically served by the web server you would still be using a URL that points to that file.

Answer (score 26):

direct_to_template no longer works in Django 1.8. Here is how to do it in 1.8, in the **urls.py**:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="your_static.html"), name='whatever'),
]
```

Comment: Do we need to do that for every static HTML?

Answer (score 20):

You can render a template without a view using the generic view [`direct_to_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template).

Redirecting to success.html isn't the way to go in django since success.html doesn't have an associated URL. You always have to bind the template to an url via a view (direct_to_template is a view which gets all its arguments from the conf in urls.py, but it's still a view)

Comment: `direct_to_template` has been deprecated; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15117932/662761) for 1.5+

Comment: That link is broken now, too.

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure this isn't what OP wanted to do, but if someone wants to render something without a view, (for sending an email or appending to other html code), you can use this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
html = render_to_string('template.html', params)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use lambda function.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', lambda request: render(request, 'homepage.html'))
]
```