# Django 1.5 index page

Tags: django

I have update my django to 1.5 and I have one problem: in urls.py I have

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^$','direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html'}),)
```

In 1.4 it works nice, but today it wrotes

```
"Could not import django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template. Parent module django.views.generic.simple does not exist."
```

I searched in google - I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940528/django-index-page-best-most-common-practice), but it the same I have in code. Please, help

Comment: Did you check doc file here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views/ ?

Comment: @FrancoisM I use 1.5, not 1.4. In 1.4 this code worked

Comment: django 1.5 doesn't have a `direct_to_template` function (which is what the error says). @Adrián López has the recommended solution

Answer (score 76, accepted):

That `direct_to_template()` function doesn't exist anymore.

Try this with a generic template view:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

Comment: **Reverse for 'list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.** I use `{% url "list"  %}`

Comment: @tim that's completely unrelated to this question, it even sounds like it's a different url altogether...

Comment: Migration guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/)