# How can i call a html template without any view in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to call `index.html` template to particular URL without calling any **view**.

is it possible in django?

Comment: Your question answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117835/django-1-5-index-page/15117932#15117932

Comment: @MubarizFeyziyev i know this method but i don't want to call any view not in url or in views.py

Comment: If you don't call anything how can you render template?

Comment: @MubarizFeyziyev yes i know it, i want do it like php

Comment: You must follow django MVT structure

Comment: @MubarizFeyziyev so it is not possible in django :-(

Comment: Maybe you want like this?
{% include "index.html" %}

Comment: No, You can't break the architectural style of `Django` that is `MTV`.

Comment: @AstikAnand,MubarizFeyziyev thanks for clearing my confusion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
     (r'^home/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Comment: i don't want to call any type of views (TemplateView.as_view)

Comment: No views is called from `views.py` here, it's just the method of calling template without defining any view function.

Comment: i know this method, but can i call a template without any function or view not in urls and not views.py

Comment: @rahul.m what are you tyring to do exactly? Or put another way - what are you expecting to happen if you could do what you're asking?

Comment: No, because you need to follow the `MTV` or `MVC` framework in django. And framework doesn't support that.

Comment: @rahul.m, you can select answer, If it helped you. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: @AstikAnand yes sure